Is the canonical quantization an isomorphism?
I'm not sure if this question is too mathematical so it could be better on the mathematics forum, but I believe theoretical physicists are equipped to answer this abstractly.
So I haven't found any book that defines the canonical quantization rigorously, so here is my attempt:
The canonical quantization $q$ is a function defined:
$q: \mathbb{P} \to V$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the phase space, and
$$V = \text{span}\left\{ \vec{x}, i\vec{\nabla}\right\}$$
such that $q(\vec{x}) = \hat{\vec{x}}, q(\vec{p}) = i \vec{\nabla}$.
Also, the phase space is an inner product space, so we define:
$$q(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) = \frac{q(\vec{a}) \cdot q(\vec{b}) + q(\vec{b}) \cdot q(\vec{a})}{2}$$
in order to keep everything Hermitian and it's easy to show things are well defined. The problem I faced is when I want to define it over the cross product:
How should I define $q(\vec{a}\times \vec{b})$?

Your notations are worrying : there is only one position operator $\hat{\vec x}$ (or, if you want, one for each dimension of the configuration space) and a continuum of points of configuration/phase space, $\vec x$ is not a point of phase space (instead it should be something like $(\vec x,\vec p)$. Quantization is usually a function that sends functions on the classical phase space to self-adjoint operators on a given Hilbert space.

ah, It's actually the same. Instead of looking at the phase space as $V_x \times V_p$, I'm looking at them as $V_x \oplus V_p$. The algebra is the same.

But I see what you're talking about. It's true that $\vec{x} \to \hat{\vec{x}}$ is inconsistent because $\hat{\vec{x}}$ is a unique operator. So instead, we define $q: F \to V$ where $F$ are functions on the phase space. Is it true if I defined it as $q(f(x,p)) = f(\hat{x}, \hat{p})$?

$q(f(x,p)) =f(\hat x,\hat p)$ is the idea and what is usually done in QM classes. However, as pointed out in the answer, this must be done carefully and with some restrictions to get something well defined.

There is no rigorous formulation of canonical quantization, among other things due to the Groenewold-van Hove theorem (see e.g. this answer of mine) stating that there is no map from functions on phase space to operators on Hilbert space that has all properties we'd like a quantization map to have.

What do we sacrifice by the dirac quantization rule?

@Habouz If you mean the "rule" that turns $x$ and $p$ into operators in canonical quantization, its problem is that it doesn't consistently turn polynomials in $x$ and $p$ into operators - classically we have $xp = px = \frac{1}{2}(xp+px)$ but quantumly these three expressions are not equal - so the "default" of canonical quantization does not actually define a map from classical observables to quantum observables, it just declares that quantum mechanical phase spaces should have operators $x$ and $p$ with $[x,p] = \mathrm{i}$ and little more.

That's true, but in your case, only one of these combinations give you a hermitian operator under the rule.

@Habouz So what? If you hope to find a unique classical symbol for a function of $x$ and $p$ that's Hermitian, that doesn't work either, since one can arbitrarily add $xp-px = 0$ classically to any symbol without changing its value, but the corresponding quantum expression changes by the commutator.
